# Flash ANE SoftKeyboard

Tags: ios, flash, keyboard, adobe, android-softkeyboard

I have a flash application made using adobe air 3.2 , there is a feature of textfield for the user, when he clicks on it, the application gets pushed up. Then when it loses focus, it will automatically get back to its initial position which is normal.

After I added an iOS native extension (ANE) to it , now when the user clicks on the textfield , the application gets pushed up but it will not restore its initial position anymore after it loses focus.

I have tried to use none in the description xml but this node is recognizable by flash!!

Any help